# how to replace the id of the div using ujs in rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ujs

I know how to do this:

[How to replace the div in Rails 3 using AJAX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5391451/how-to-replace-the-div-in-rails-3-using-ajax)

But while that replaces the content of the div, it doesn't change the id value of the div.

How can I change the id of the div (along with its content)?

Comment: Have you read up on JavaScript or jQuery?

Comment: Some. I'm working with dinamycally generated divs, and right now I'm just hiding the ancient div and showing the new one. I don't know if this is the best method, hence my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set `id` attribute for the div:

```
$("#your_div").html(...); # here you set div content
$("#your_div").attr("id", "new_id"); #the div now has new_id id
```